# Why does matplotlib produce linear graph for a data list?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm simply trying to plot the `app_mag` list which was read in from a file and appended to the list. When I do `print(app_mag)` it displays the correct data in the correct format `['20.376', '20.050', '19.534'...]`. The data should produce a smooth oscillating curve but the output graph shows a linear increase over x which doesn't fit with the list at all.

Here's the code and graph:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app_mag = []
with open("randytung_months.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[1:]:
        lines = line.split()
        app_mag.append(lines[8])
        
print(app_mag)

plt.plot(app_mag, 'rx')
plt.show()
```

[Output graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jye6W.png)

Also, from the graph, if there is an easy way to not have all the labels bunched together on the y-axis, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your data is string typed. Did you try convert them to numeric, e.g. float?

Comment: `app_mag.append(float(lines[8]))`

Comment: Perfect thank you, it works as I thought now